# How to let control set its own property if event fires

Tags: wpf, events, xaml, controls

How can I have a control's property to be set to a specific value, if a event of the same control fires?

Let's say I have an *expander*

```
 <Expander Header="Click to expand" GotFocus="IsExpanded=True" />
```

And I want to set the IsExpanded Property to true, if it got Focus.
How can I do this in *Xaml*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx), probably something like this:

```
 <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Adrian's approach is the cleanest way to reach your goal. However, if you want to change a property when an event fires, you can try this:

```
<Expander Header="Click to expand">
  <Expander.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Expander">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Expander.IsExpanded)">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Expander.Style>
</Expander>
```

Note: this is purely from memory, and may not work as-is. But it should give you a good idea of how this could be accomplished.

Comment: I tried your suggestion using the event *MouseEnter* instead of *GotFocus* (because it's easier to fire ;) ) and I get a *System.Windows.Media.Animation.AnimationStorage.OnCurrentTimeInvalidated* Exception. If I change the *KeyTime*'s value to *1*, no exception occurs, but the expander does not expand if I touch it with the mouse...